# openvswitch: How to turn ON the bridge?

Tags: openstack, openvswitch

I am trying to configure an ovs bridge to connect to a controller. I notice that it sends the HELLO but does not complete the connection. I see the following:

```
 ovs-ofctl show br-flowmon
 OFPT_FEATURES_REPLY (xid=0x2): dpid:deadbeefdeadbeef
 n_tables:254, n_buffers:0
 capabilities: FLOW_STATS TABLE_STATS PORT_STATS QUEUE_STATS ARP_MATCH_IP
 actions: output enqueue set_vlan_vid set_vlan_pcp strip_vlan mod_dl_src mod_dl_dst mod_nw_src mod_nw_dst mod_nw_tos mod_tp_src mod_tp_dst
 1(patch-flowmon1): addr:26:1f:db:26:99:4a
    config:     0
    state:      0
    speed: 0 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
 LOCAL(br-flowmon): addr:56:ea:36:94:4b:4e
    config:     PORT_DOWN
    state:      LINK_DOWN
    speed: 0 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
 OFPT_GET_CONFIG_REPLY (xid=0x4): frags=normal miss_send_len=0
```

I suspect that it does not complete the connection because the config state is PORT_DOWN. How can I "turn on" the port? Is there any other possible reason for this behavior?

(is there an ovs-vsctl or ovs-ofctl command to do this?)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ifconfig br-flowmon up

Fixed the issue but I still don't see a completed connection at the controller. Any clues?